# Alacritty - Open files with a click

Tags: macos, iterm2, alacritty

- MacOS v14.3.1
- Alacritty v0.13.1

iTerm2 has a feature where you can Cmd + click on any file path and it will open it. This is super useful, especially when testing. Click on the failed test and it's open in VSCode.

Any way to achieve this in Alacritty?